# Inner join three tables seems wrong

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I want to inner join three tables with condition.
One condition is DAT.STATE_ID IN ('7','8','9').
The count is 116 with below query.

```
select count(*) from "B_TRACE"."P_TC_DATA" DAT WHERE DAT."STATE_ID" IN ('7','8','9');
```

However, the count grow to 146 as join three tables with below query.
The count number should be less than 116. It seems not right.
What's wrong with the inner join query?

```
SELECT DAT.*, SUBID.*, TR.* 
FROM "B_TRACE"."P_TC_DATA" AS DAT, 
    "B_CC"."CC_CONSENT_RECORD" AS SUBID, 
    "B_TRACE"."P_TC_RECORD" AS TR
WHERE TR."P_SERIAL_ID" = SUBID."SUBJECT_ID" 
    AND TR."P_SERIAL_ID" = DAT."P_SERIAL_ID" 
    AND  (DAT."STATE_ID" IN ('7','8','9')) 
    AND (SUBID."SUBJECT_C_ID" IS NOT NULL)
```

Another try, got 146 rows still

```
SELECT DATS.*, SUBID.*, TR.* 
FROM (select * from "B_TRACE"."P_TC_DATA" DAT WHERE DAT."STATE_ID" IN ('7','8','9')) AS DATS, 
    "B_CC"."CC_CONSENT_RECORD" AS SUBID, 
    "B_TRACE"."P_TC_RECORD" AS TR
WHERE TR."P_SERIAL_ID" = SUBID."SUBJECT_ID" 
    AND TR."P_SERIAL_ID" = DATS."P_SERIAL_ID"  
    AND (SUBID."SUBJECT_C_ID" IS NOT NULL)
```

some try

```
--got 379 rows
SELECT  SUBID.*, TR.* 
FROM  
    "B_CC"."CC_CONSENT_RECORD" AS SUBID, 
    "B_TRACE"."P_TC_RECORD" AS TR
WHERE TR."P_SERIAL_ID" = SUBID."SUBJECT_ID" 


--got 91 rows
SELECT DATS.*, SUBID.* 
FROM (SELECT * FROM "B_TRACE"."P_TC_DATA" DAT WHERE DAT."STATE_ID" IN ('7','8','9')) AS DATS, 
    "B_CC"."CC_CONSENT_RECORD" AS SUBID,    
WHERE SUBID."SUBJECT_ID"=DATS."P_SERIAL_ID" 


--got 181 rows  
SELECT DATS.*, TR.* 
FROM (SELECT * FROM "B_TRACE"."P_TC_DATA" DAT WHERE DAT."STATE_ID" IN ('7','8','9')) AS DATS,  
    "B_TRACE"."P_TC_RECORD" AS TR
WHERE TR."P_SERIAL_ID" = DATS."P_SERIAL_ID"
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `ON`.

Comment: When you join tables, the results shows the combination of rows using the relationship you specify. This could lead to more rows than the primary table has, depending on the relationship between the tables. Please add the table structure of them to understand the question better, specifically the **foreign key** relationships.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried, got 146 rows still. cant figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below explicit join

```
    SELECT DAT.*, SUBID.*, TR.* 
    FROM "B_TRACE"."P_TC_RECORD" AS TR join
    "B_CC"."CC_CONSENT_RECORD" AS SUBID on TR."P_SERIAL_ID" = SUBID."SUBJECT_ID"
    join "B_TRACE"."P_TC_DATA" AS DAT on TR."P_SERIAL_ID" = DAT."P_SERIAL_ID"
     where
     AND  DAT."STATE_ID" IN ('7','8','9')
     AND SUBID."SUBJECT_C_ID" IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @fink168 does you use distinct ?

Comment: Nope. No distinct

Comment: You could try by using distinct

Comment: still got 146 rows with distinct

Answer (score 0):

There are probably duplicate SUBJECT_ID in CC_CONSENT_RECORD.  So for each duplicate it adds to the count when joined to P_TC_DATA.

You can test this

```
SELECT CONS.SUBJECT_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM B_TRACE.P_TC_DATA AS DATA
JOIN B_CC.CC_CONSENT_RECORD AS CONS 
  ON CONS.SUBJECT_ID = DATA.P_SERIAL_ID
WHERE DATA.STATE_ID IN ('7', '8', '9')
GROUP BY CONS.SUBJECT_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

And here's an alternative for the query

```
SELECT DATA.*, CONS.*, REC.* 
FROM B_TRACE.P_TC_DATA AS DATA
JOIN B_CC.CC_CONSENT_RECORD AS CONS 
  ON (CONS.SUBJECT_ID = DATA.P_SERIAL_ID AND CONS.SUBJECT_C_ID IS NOT NULL)
LEFT JOIN B_TRACE.P_TC_RECORD AS REC 
  ON REC.P_SERIAL_ID = DATA.P_SERIAL_ID
WHERE DATA.STATE_ID IN ('7', '8', '9')
```